# Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku -- tried other solutions but to no avail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

Don't mark this as duplicate because I've tried the other solutions but I'm still getting this error. I accidentally put `gem 'sqlite3'` not under `:development` and now I keep getting the `Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku` error when I try to `git push heroku master`. I've confirmed that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` does work, which is what the error message suggests.

Here is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use Haml as the templating library
gem 'haml'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails' 
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg' # for Heroku deployment
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

And here is the Gemfile.lock, which I've deleted and regenerated

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.5.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    arel (6.0.3)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (8.2.2)
    capybara (2.6.2)
      addressable
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.1)
    cucumber (2.3.3)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      cucumber-core (~> 1.4.0)
      cucumber-wire (~> 0.0.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 3.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      multi_test (>= 0.1.2)
    cucumber-core (1.4.0)
      gherkin (~> 3.2.0)
    cucumber-rails (1.4.3)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2, < 3)
      cucumber (>= 1.3.8, < 3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      railties (>= 3, < 5)
    cucumber-rails-training-wheels (1.0.0)
      cucumber-rails (>= 1.1.1)
    cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
    database_cleaner (1.5.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    gherkin (3.2.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.99.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.8.4)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multi_test (0.1.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    pg (0.18.4)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.5.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.5.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
    railties (4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.1.1)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec-core (3.4.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-support (3.4.1)
    sass (3.4.21)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (1.6.4)
    sprockets (3.5.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.2)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  capybara
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  cucumber-rails
  cucumber-rails-training-wheels
  database_cleaner
  haml
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  launchy
  pg
  rails (= 4.2.5.1)
  rails_12factor
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.11.2
```

I'm not very experienced with ruby/rails so there may be something glaring obvious that I'm missing but I've tried the other solutions to this problem but I'm getting no where.

Comment: did you update your database.yml to use postgres instead of sqlite?

Comment: @maxpleaner yes, but unsure if I did so correctly, I followed these instructions though: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3. I'm going off past class/assignment which I had to deploy to heroku and I looked that their database.yml and they used sqlite so idk why those worked fine but now that I'm doing this from scratch its giving me errors. Can I change only the `production` in the .yml since my gemfile has it only in `production` and `sqlite` for test and development or is that not how it works?

Comment: i think you actually dont need a production section as heroku generates one for you. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) and look for the database.yml example. By the way, you can automate the postgres setup by using `rails new AppName -d postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

Getting a SQLite error even though it is not in the Gemfile:

If you’ve removed the gem 'sqlite3' line from your Gemfile and are still getting errors while deploying to Heroku it is likely that another gem you are using has sqlite3 as a dependency. To help find the source of this dependency look in your Gemfile.lock for sqlite3. Find the gem that has sqlite3 as a dependency and remove it from your Gemfile. Once you’ve done this run bundle install and ensure that sqlite3 no longer exists in your Gemfile.

From [devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

So it appears to be that you should install posgresql locally and use that primarily. It is best practice to maintain database parity on dev and production servers anyway.